# How to restrict user to select current or previous time for Today and select any time for past dates in time picker dialog

Tags: android, android-timepicker

As i have written in title i wanna restrict user to select only current or past time for Today and can pick any time for past dates . Please tell me how to do this in android. I have added restriction to date picker by using `setMaxDate();` method but unable to do same in time picker so please tell me how should i do this.

Comment: Did you get the answer @Shivam i am also have same issue in TimePicker... I want to restrict user to select future time

Answer (score 0):

try

```
setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); only works for Date Picker dialog